# Referencing between multiple Excel sheets embedded in Word relative to its file path

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ole, embedding

I've searched the internet thin, and not being proficient in VBA myself, I've come to you for help.

**The question:**

In a Word file, I have embedded multiple Excel sheets with text in between them like so:

Text... Text... Text...

"*embedded Excel file*"

Text... Text... Text...

"*another embedded Excel file*"

By opening both embedded Excel files at the same time, (right click -> Worksheet object -> Open object) I am able to link cells to one another in the traditional way (click inside cell and type "=", click on the cell in the other sheet). This allows me to calculate stuff in the second file, based on values from the first file.

The problem is, that if I send this to a colleague as a template, the filepath/filename will change, and then the reference from the two sheets won't work anymore.

Is there a way around this?

**Context:**

I wish to create a template to be used for business cases. The template should be so easy to use, that the user only has to enter very specific numbers, and the rest will be calculated automatically, graphs will be updated automatically etc. Relevant text has to be entered between numbers to provide a solid case.

***EDIT1:*** I must add, that the Excel files are created within Word, and have no file paths themselves.

***EDIT2:*** If you were able to display different parts / sheets from the same embedded Excel file, different places in the word document - that could be a way around it, but I have not discovered a way to do so.

***EDIT3:*** When linking cells from the two embedded documents, it does so by using the current filepath. The problem is that I want this as a template, which means the filepath/filename will change, and therefore it cannot be static. I need it to be dynamic/relative to the name/path of the file itself.